# Cant change input focus inside table using keyUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a series of text inputs where the focus changes to the next input on keyUp when maxLength is reached, this I can do but the problem I am having is when the text inputs are inside a table I cant get the focus to change to the input in the next cell over.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputField').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
            $(this).next('.inputField').focus();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputField" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputField" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" class="inputField" /></td>
<table>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzgs6wmn/

I have tried changing ('.inputField') to ('input') and ('input.inputField') and I have also tried giving the table a class then using the table class to get to input, but any combination of paths I have tried wont change the focus so I'm not sure what I'm meant to use when accessing input tags inside a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the inputs are inside **td** tags, you must first reference the parent, then do next and find the child that has the class you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputField').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
        $(this).parent().next().find('.inputField').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was paying to much attention to trying to reference both the parent and the child in the second line I didn't think of using .find in the third line.